# Advanced javascript and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I need a very quick response, the best today 28 November 2016. What should I learn in javascript to be able to create advanced Google Analytics implementations?

I mean - only basic javascript knowledge is required, or should I learn JSON , AngularJS etc. ?

I know only basis javascript and need to know in which exact direction should I go.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Everything, don't learn a language just because you need it for a specfic project.

Comment: I would start with http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks, but those two answers are not answer I need and I am looking for. I know people use javascript in GA. But I also know they use something much bore advance than basis javascript. That's why I am asking and I need a response from specialist who creates and implements advanced javascript code for advanced GA statistics gathering. So, don't try to teach someone who is 35 years old, but answer correctly. If you want to write something what isn't rhe exact answer for my question, just don't write please.

Answer (score 0):

I use a lot of javascript as part of the Google tag manager implementations.  Understanding the basics of javascript is a must have.
- Code academy has a great javascript course. 
- I would then look at basic Dom manipulation. ([W3C is a good starting point](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp))

- after that - setup your own website/ blog and try out new things on there! You will learn more from doing it for yourself. 
  Hope the journey goes well - I really love using my programming skills to solve business problems and help surface data to customers.